# How to set the current scale to 1?

Tags: modeling

I want to take an object that I have scaled in object mode and set the current scale to 1. I can find the current scale, clear the scale with Alt+S, and then switch to edit mode and scale to what it was before I cleared the scale. Is there a built in way to do this? Modifiers build off of the object scale, so it would be nice to set the current scale as 1 rather than just clearing the scale and resizing in edit mode.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the object that you want to apply the scale to,  press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  and select **Scale**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

- Apply Scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> You will see a menu

[image]